# ASP.NET GridView Paging Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, paging

I have searched through stack overflow and Google but I could not find an answer that would work for my situation and I tried a lot of them.

I have an issue with an ASP.NET gridview. When the page first loads the grid is attached to a Data Source ID and displays the records with paging that works.

Now if the user filters the data the first page of returned records is displayed but if they click on 'Page 2' in the gridview footer the page flashes but does not change the data or pages.

Also I have noticed that when the search is applied there are 10 plus pages displayed in the footer no matter how many records are returned.

Here is the ASP.NET GridView header code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSOHeader" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1010px" CellPadding="4" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" AllowSorting="True" 
AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvSOHeaderOnPageIndexChanging" 
PageSize="15" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
```

When the user searches here is the code that reassigns the grid view datasource:

```
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(myConnection)
        conn.Open()
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
            sqlCmd.CommandText = strText
            sqlCmd.Connection = conn
            Using sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                Using sqlDT As New DataTable
                    sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
                    If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        gvSOHeader.DataSourceID = String.Empty
                        gvSOHeader.DataSource = Nothing
                        gvSOHeader.DataSource = sqlDT
                        gvSOHeader.DataBind()
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
```

This works but only is as far as it displays the first page of returned results. I can not page to any other results page.

Here is the OnPageIndexChanging event code:

```
Protected Sub gvSOHeaderOnPageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gvSOHeader.PageIndexChanging

    gvSOHeader.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    gvSOHeader.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I have also noticed that the OnPgeIndexChanging event fires twice but I do not know why. I tried adding an If statement to the OnPageIndexChanging to check for Not IsPostback but it still will not display more than the first page of searched data.

I am sorry if this is a duplicate but I could not find a result that fit my situation. Any help would be very greatly received.
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if it's a matter of where you're setting the datasource.  It sounds as if the pages are for a much larger, initial set of data.  [this example does the datasource assignment PLUS binding in the paging events](https://forums.asp.net/t/1935490.aspx?GridView+pages+are+blank+after+pagination+)

Comment: Yes the initial data is about 10K records but the search/filter returns about a max of 1K. If that helps.

Comment: Since there is no answer I am going to assume that I am going about this the wrong way and have to try some other option.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you read that link you'd see that they're adding code into places like OnPaging to make it work.  With the information so far, it's hard to give you a definitive answer, if that makes sense?  Where is `code that reassigns the grid view datasource` getting called from?

Comment: I read that but that's not what is happening. If I have refined the data by user search and it returns more than one page of results, when i click on page 2, in the grid view footer, it shows page two of the original data, not the filtered/searched results.

Comment: No one has any other ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to have the code in the `OnPaging`.  The answer likely lies between "When the user searches" and where the data is getting filtered.  You've described the problem entirely when you used the expression "original data"

Comment: I finally had to change the filtering because I could not get it to work. But I have it working now by spawning a new page with a separate grid view that has only filtered data. Work around but its ok for internal use. Would never do this for an outside site though.
Thanks for all the help. Not sure how to vote for anyone though? :(